# UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented error with hybrid Android app using Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, appium-android

I am writing automated test cases for a hybrid Android app using Appium.
I am using below line of code to set the cursor on a drop-down/pop-up:

```
Set<String> stringSet =  webDriver.getWindowHandles();
```

However, this gives below error as:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented.
```

**webdriver** is the object of **AppiumDriver**.

This is a **Hybrid**(Cordova) **Mobile App**.

My stack trace:

```
Apr 03, 2019 4:20:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown method' (405 expected)

org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'VIKSHAH-M-F1AR', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '1.8.0_152-release'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
```

**Update**:
After Updating the JDK

```
Apr 10, 2019 12:47:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown method' (405 expected)

org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'VIKSHAH2-M-F1AR', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
```

Has anyone faced similar issue? 
Is there any other way to test drop down using Appium?

Comment: getWindowHandles() is typically used in a traditional web browser.  I can't think of any reason to use it with an Appium driver.  Perhaps you mean to be using getContextHandles()?

Comment: The original poster is unresponsive to his own question, and yet this question managed to make it to the Stack Overflow Newsletter.  If I could, I'd downvote it again.

Comment: @BillHileman I'm working on a hybrid app so basically, the entire application renders on web view. and I can't find elements of a pop-up window, so now can you please explain to me how getContextHandles() will work instead of getWindowHandles () ???

Comment: I'll post an example of my own code that switches to the first available web context as a suggested answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown method' (405 expected)
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'VIKSHAH-M-F1AR', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '1.8.0_152-release' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* variant was unable to interact with the desired *WebElement(s)*.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.141.59** of *2018-11-14T08:17:03* which is a recent release.
- Your *JDK* version is **1.8.0_152-release** which is pretty **old** and **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.141.59* and JDK v1.8.0_152-release.

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [JDK 8u202](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Probably because the explanation is wrong. How did you get from `Method has not yet been implemented` to `unable to interact with the desired WebElement`? The OP gets the error on `getWindowHandles()`.

Comment: Thanks, @DebanjanB for your kind response.

Comment: I update my JDK  to 1.8.0_202 but still, I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Apr 10, 2019 12:23:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown method' (405 expected)

org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Method has not yet been implemented
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'VIKSHAH2-M-F1AR', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:1046:c26d:1be1:cb9e%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` property? There is an additional step necessary within your app build, unfortunately. As described in the Android remote debugging docs it is necessary to set to true the `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` property on the `android.webkit.WebView` element.

If not yet enabled, ask the developers to set to true before generating the build.

Comment: Thanks, for your response.

@Uday Seshardri ,
 As I mentioned above this is Hybrid App not Native and what I found for setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled is this : 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Comment: Even if it’s an hybrid app. Android manifest.xml file will be present.

Comment: Find some answer from the below link

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that I use to switch to the first web view (non-native view) from available contexts.  If you're not sure what the context texts actually contain, then write code to capture the array and display all the values.

```
@Nullable
private String getWebContext() {
    ArrayList<String> contexts = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getContextHandles());
    for (String context : contexts) {
        if (!context.equals("NATIVE_APP")) {
            return context;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this didn't work for me in my scenario.
actually, this is my main issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708412/can-not-able-to-find-elements-of-drop-down 
and when I'm trying to getting elements of drop-down using webDriver.getWindowHandles() this error occurs.